# Linkedhashmap<String,Object>

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset, linkedhashmap

I need guidance to iterate through a `LinkedHashMap` with below values

```
{"8":{"Name":"test","city":"ny"}, "9":{"Name":"test","city":"ny"}}
```

I am able to display key as `8` and value as `{"Name":"test","city":"ny"}`

but I'am trying to display `Name` and `city` as key value inside key `8`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where is your effort?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: You probably need to use some getter on your value, something like `getName`

Comment: What kind of Object is in the value field?
How did the data came into the LinkedHashMap?

Comment: Your data looks like JSON. How exactly you are creating that map? What type of objects does it store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks like JSON so maybe you are looking for solution using JSON parser.
For instance with [`org.json`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) package your code can look like:

```
String jsonStr =  "{\"8\":{\"Name\":\"test1\",\"city\":\"ny1\"},"
                + " \"9\":{\"Name\":\"test2\",\"city\":\"ny2\"}}";

JSONObject parent = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

for (Object key : parent.keySet()){
    JSONObject childObject = parent.getJSONObject(key.toString());

    System.out.println("-----------");
    System.out.println(childObject);
    System.out.println("Name = "+childObject.get("Name"));
    System.out.println("city = "+childObject.get("city"));
}
```

Output:

```
-----------
{"city":"ny1","Name":"test1"}
Name = test1
city = ny1
-----------
{"city":"ny2","Name":"test2"}
Name = test2
city = ny2
```

Comment: Thank you buddy !! that helps

Answer (score 0):

Given your value of the Hashmap is just a plain String, then you can use this:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
linkedHashMap.put("8", "{\"Name\":\"test\",\"city\":\"ny\"}");

String value = (String)linkedHashMap.get("8");
String split[] = value.split("\"");

System.out.println(split[3]);
System.out.println(split[7]);
```